# background-color on body css doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

I'm trying to edit my `app.scss` on my Symfony 4 project.

But the `background-color` doesn't work.

```
body {
  background-color: #ccccff;
}
```

On my base.html.twig, I've this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            {% block title %}Welcome!
            {% endblock %}
        </title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/app.scss" rel="stylesheet">
        <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" rel="stylesheet"> {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        </head>

        <body>
            {% include "components/sidebar/sidebarHeader.html.twig" %}
            <div class="col-md-12"> {% block body %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
                {% include "components/sidebar/sidebarFooter.html.twig" %}

                {# TODO: Trouver un moyen d'insérer <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> au lieu du footer sidebar #}
                <script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
            </body>
        </html>
```

The only solution that is working is to edit directly the `bootstrap.min.css`.

However, if I edit my `app.scss`, if it is after my bootstrap.min.css on the base.html.twig, why it doesn't work ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're not using webpack?

Comment: you have to compile the `.scss` into `.css` first

Comment: What is handling the .scss file? the browser just ignores it

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#webpack-encore

Comment: Try to include your css after all other css on the page. The AwesomeFont css is pulled in after yours; it might be overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! So, for webpack, I will use it at the end of my project :)
I will try to make css and not a scss, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in your code example...

`<link href="/css/app.scss" rel="stylesheet">`

However, a browser doesn't know what to do with it, since it's pre-compiled css.  You need to replace that line with:

`<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">`

And actually compile the scss file using [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/install).  Make sure the compiled css file is in the same location as the Sass file, or you'll need to change the path.

Comment: No problem... you should mark this as your accepted answer to resolve this issue so people don't still think you need assistance.